# How to get a php variable in jquery function?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I want to pass a php variable in jquery function. Actually i m generating a dynamic php variable .

```
$imageslider = "imageslider_".$convertcode;
```

`$imageslider` is div of image gallery slider which i want to show on click on an icon.
Icon div is also generated dyanamically by the following code

```
$paletlyicon = "paletlyicon_".$convertcode;
```

Now i have a jquery function as follows

```
jQuery('<?php echo '.'.$paletlyicon ; ?> ').hover(function()
  {   
jQuery('<?php echo '.'.$imageslider ; ?>').show();
   });
```

This is not working somehow ..i tried to alert the dynamic variables but they r showing nothing..
Plz look into it..

Comment: Looks OK to me, assuming you're trying to match a class name of `paletlyicon_XXX`. And presumably it is actually a PHP script, not a .js file?

Comment: Your code is technically correct. Are you sure the $paletlyicon variable is populating as you expect it to? Please provide us the rendered source of the page with the jQuery code.

Comment: alert('<?php echo "#".$paletlyicon; ?> '); this is showing me only # in alert...

Comment: so your variable is undefined or an empty string. we cannot say why without the complete code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey what are the dom you define to ?
a class or a id ?
Change to :

```
$imageslider = ".imageslider_".$convertcode; //Add '.' add first
```

and

```
$paletlyicon = ".paletlyicon_".$convertcode; //Add '.' add first
```

So if you don't add '.' or '#', you define to manipulate the dom named `paletlyicon_".$convertcode`

Good luck